# Qt 5 and C++11 (qobjectdefs_impl.h won't compile)

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5

NB: I have tried asking this question [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/31105/) (on the Qt Project forums), but to no avail for the moment, so I'm trying my luck here.

I’m using Qt 5.0.1 (on a laptop with Ubuntu 13.04), the compiler is gcc 4.7.3 (and I'm working with Qt Creator 2.7.0).

In order to have C++11 working, it seems that simply adding the following line to the .pro file of the project does the trick (or at least it's supposed to):

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

However, when I do that, I get a ton of errors in the file qobjectdefs_impl.h upon compilation.

Anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is a screenshot so that you can see what the errors look like (apparently the errors happen when I do `#include <QColor>`):
[image]

NB: [link](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B41pJbehW4QbSjNsVVNvcmsyanM) to the image if it shows too small here.

Edit: I still have the errors after having upgraded to gcc 4.8.1 and Qt 5.1.2, which I compiled from the sources.

Comment: Hmm, I can understand that you don't get an answer. I just tried delegating constructors with gcc 4.8 and Qt 5.1.1. Works like a charm. So either it is a bug in Qt 5.0.1, which would mean that no one cares since this bug is already fixed, or it is a bug in your setup. In that case it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: I guess I could just upgrade to gcc 4.8 and Qt 5.1.1 then? (I hope that's easy). NB: I'll add a screenshot so that you can see what the errors look like

Comment: No guarantee. I just started a small project, added CONFIG += c++11 and created a delegating constructor. That was all I could do. At least we know that when you upgrade to gcc 4.8 and Qt 5.1.1 and the problem still exists, that it is not Qt or the gcc. Btw... I compiled my Qt myself. With c++11 flag. But I don't know if this makes a difference for programs, which use the lib,

Comment: Ok, after I saw you screenshot I can speculate more: I think your Qt version was compiled without c++11 support. This is without problems possible. Certain features are just not available then. Now you activate c++11 for your program. Might be that this causes the compiler to try to access functions in Qt, which are not available. But as I said: Pure speculation.

Comment: I asked on the Qt interest mailing list. Good chances to get an answer there, whether or not the problem could be a Qt, which was compiled without C++11 support.

Comment: Thanks for all that! NB: I installed Qt on my computer by doing `apt-get install qtcreator`, so I guess I have the latest package available in the repos of Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Tsk, why involve most of the problems I tried to solve here today Ubuntu?

Comment: Really? Well, I guess that makes me glad more and more people are using it ;) Anyway, it's still Qt5 (I would have thought it "automatically" had C++11 support)

Comment: Nope, depends on the compiler. For some compilers/platforms Qt must be 'told' to use C++11 features. But this does not matter. I got my responses. Whether or not C++11 is compiled in Qt has nothing to do whether a program, which links to it uses C++11 or not. You really only use delegated constructors? No slots with lamda functions?

Comment: Actually, I got rid of the delegated constructors, so right now I use no C++11 code. I get all the errors simply by adding CONFIG += c++11 in the .pro file.

Comment: I forwarded it to the mailing list. But I must say... I have to give up. No idea, what the problem could be. Some C++11 features were already in Qt 4.8. I never heard about this CONFIG+=C++11 bug. I can only imagine that Ubuntu somehow botched the installation. Strange patches, whatever. I always compile my Qt from sources myself. Maybe this is the reason I have so few problems, that I have to try to help others, so I can learn more. ;-D

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for helping anyway. I guess I'll try to upgrade gcc and Qt manually, or compile it from the sources. I just went for the simplest install with apt-get install...

Comment: OK so I upgraded to gcc 4.8.1 and Qt 5.1.2, which I compiled from the sources and... I still have the errors :(

Comment: Problem solved after all, see answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Yay, someone (JKSH) found what the problem was on Qt Project forums ([here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/31105/)).

In short:
The problem was that I had written somewhere `#define I complex(0.0, 1.0)`, which created a name clash in qobjectdefs_impl.h (where `complex` was a typedef for `std::complex<double>`). For some (weird) reason that didn’t cause any problems as long as I didn’t write CONFIG = c+11 in the pro file, but not it did after writing it.

Many thanks to JKSH, and also Greenflow for helping!

Edit: The credit for finding the issue should go to Thiago Macieira from the Qt Project Interest mailing list, see comment.

Comment: To be fair: the actual analysis was done by somebody else on the development@qt-project.org mailinglist. http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2013-August/008264.html

Comment: You're very right, I just realized that (JKSH says it on the Qt Project thread). So, great team work and hats off to Thiago Macieira, I'm very impressed.